# Detect browser language with NextJS built-in i18n

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, next.js

Is there a way to implement language detection in Next with the default language detection, or will I have to use a 3rd party package? Couldn't find anything in the docs.

I want the initial language be based on user's browser language.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing or if you were asking about doing this client side, then use this code (and set state) in a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array: `navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage`.

Comment: "I want the initial language be based on user's browser language" - That's what Next.js does by default. Next.js automatically detects which locale to use based on the `Accept-Language` header.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Detect the browser's preferred language
    const browserLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    const supportedLocales = ['en', 'tr'];
    let detectedLocale = 'en'; // fallback to 'en-US' if the browser's language is not supported

    if (supportedLocales.includes(browserLang)) {
      detectedLocale = browserLang;
    }

    // If the user hits the root path, redirect based on the browser's language
    if (router.pathname === '/') {
      router.replace(`/${detectedLocale}`);
    }
  }, [router.pathname]);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```